# Dynamically building DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE, Execute Immediate doesn't work

Tags: oracle, plsql, external-tables, execute-immediate, dbms-output

I'm facing an issue when I'm trying to build a table dynamically using DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE inside a stored procedure or packaged program. A dbms_ouput.put_line of the dynamic code will  produce the correct code which i can copy and run in a new session no problem, but not inside the PROC or PACKAGE. Error: Development - ORA-06550: line 1, column 1:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CLOUD' must be declared

```
select *
  from USER_SYS_PRIVS; 

username privilege              admin_option
TEST     CREATE RULE SET             NO
TEST     CREATE TABLE                NO
TEST     CREATE EVALUATION CONTEXT   NO
TEST     SELECT ANY DICTIONARY       NO
TEST     CREATE JOB                  NO
TEST    CREATE RULE NO
```

Test PROC

```
create or replace procedure test
 AS
 
l_cloud_statement clob;
L_error_msg       varchar2(4000);


begin

        l_cloud_statement:= 'BEGIN'||CHR(13)||
                                                'DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE('||CHR(13)||
                                                'table_name => ''TESTING_EXT_TAB'','||CHR(13)||
                                                'credential_name => ''TEST_OBJ_STORE'','||CHR(13)||
                                                'file_uri_list => ''https://objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com/n/rks6fos4/b/bucketuploads/o/testing_tab.csv'','||CHR(13)||
                                                'format => json_object(''delimiter'' value '','',''skipheaders'' value ''1''),'||CHR(13)||
                                                'column_list => ''col1  varchar2(200)'');'||chr(13)||                                        
                                                'END;';


dbms_output.put_line(l_cloud_statement);

execute IMMEDIATE l_cloud_statement;

exception
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
    L_error_msg := SQLERRM;
    TEST_SYSTEM.log_error(GP_error_msg,
                                'TEST',         -- program
                                'DEV',                              -- error type
                                '0001',                          -- error code
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,
                                1);


end;
```

OUPUT CODE that works when executed in a new session

```
BEGIN

DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE(
table_name => 'TESTING_EXT_TAB',
credential_name => 'TEST_OBJ_STORE',
file_uri_list =>
'https://objectstorage.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com/n/rks6fos4/b/bucketuploads/o/testing_tab.csv',
format => json_object('delimiter' value ',','skipheaders' value '1'),
column_list => 'col1  varchar2(200)');
END;
```

Any idea what I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting a definer's rights versus invoker's rights problem and need to add `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` to the procedure declaration.

SQL statements and anonymous PL/SQL blocks run with invoker's rights by default, which means they can use all of the direct privileges, system privileges, and role privileges. PL/SQL objects, such as a procedure, run with definer's rights by default, which means they cannot use role privileges. (I believe this is because roles can be selectively enabled or disabled, so when you compile a procedure you can't know for sure what roles will be enabled when it runs.)

If `DBMS_CLOUD` is only granted to your user through a role, you will need to recompile the PL/SQL object with invoker's rights, like this:

```
create or replace procedure test authid current_user is
...
```

Comment: thank you for the help. It worked by assigning the privilege to my user.